# install shield referenced project dll

Tags: c#, asp.net, installshield-le

I am trying to make an (web for IIS) installer package with install shield limited edition. I added the project primary output and content files and debug symbols to the installer, the setup is built, it is installed correctly but now the problem:

Two of the main project referenced projects dlls are not properly built, meaning that an old version of that dll is built and copied in the setup. My (installed) website doesn't work with those because i changed that projects before making the installer.

If i copy the that dll's from the project manually into the installed folder it works.. . My question is : Where does Installshield get those dlls when building the setup? it shouldn't build the project again and add the new(just built) referenced dlls?

Also if i delete my temporary files from Microsoft.net folder in windows it builds correctly the setup(meaning that the dll's are built at that time). On the setup project at 'dependencies' i have marked all the projects i am using for the main project..

I am using VS 2012 and IShield limited edition 2012.

Answer (score 1):

I've been including DLLs in my main project's bin\release folder in the installshield 2012 LE projects by adding them to the [INSTALLDIR] in the 'Files' section. HTH

Comment: ok, but this it won't get the dll that i wanted into the bin folder from wwwroot folder of inetpub.(IIS default folder). what you are saying it will work for other types of applications but not for websites..., or i didn't made it  work... . And also installshield should be build all the projects you(I) added to configuration manager when i make the installer package... . If any other solution... . I installed GAC browser to see if that version of file is on there and it isn't, that version of dll it doesn't exists on my computer.

Comment: InstallShield get's dll from older version off app from the svn? it is very annoying to manual copy..

Comment: Seems that after I modified the assembly and committed to SVN, build again the setup, the last version of the dll was included in the setup. What is strange is that the setup with debug configuration had no problem. I am using InstallShield 2012 LE.hope someone has a good fix/explanation about this issue.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue today. My .NET project had a DLL inside it that the project referenced. InstallShield was building the MSI with an old version of that DLL.

Clearing the `Temporary ASP.NET Files` folders resolved the issue. Wasn't able to diagnose why InstallShield has this issue.

Here are the paths specifically that I cleared:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Temporary ASP.NET Files
```

Comment: yes, in the first post i said that it works if i clear those files, but "happy" to see that someone else is having this kind of problems... not found a resolution yet...

Comment: This has been driving me crazy for months! I've been manually copying the files. Sooooooo glad to have a better solution. I just wish InstallSheild wasn't so obtuse!

Comment: I cleared Temporary ASP.NET Files and it did not fix the issue.